# Playing from a large number of sound files

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm making an Alphabet program where if you enter "A B C" and press a button it would play the sound file for A and then the sound file for B and so on.

Currently I use a queue to store the all the uri that link to the sound files like so

```
switch (word)
{
    case "A": 
        uriQueue.Enqueue(new Uri("Assets/A.wav", UriKind.Relative));
        break;
    case "B":
        uriQueue.Enqueue(new Uri("Assets/B.wav", UriKind.Relative));
        break;
    case "C":
...
```

Is there a better way to do this with a large number of sound files beside using a really long switch statement and manually type in each case?

Comment: Use string concatenation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your `word` is always guaranteed to match your file name, you can drop the entire `switch` block and replace it with

```
uriQueue.Enqueue(new Uri("Assets/" + word + ".wav", UriKind.Relative));
```

Otherwise, you can use a

```
Dictionary<string,string> d;
```

that you populate with the letters as keys and the paths as values and then use

```
uriQueue.Enqueue(new Uri(d[word], UriKind.Relative));
```